# How do I use Perl's Google::Search to look for specific URLs?

Tags: perl, google-api, perl-module

The Google::Search module, which is based on the AJAX Search API, doesn't seems to work very well, or it is just me?

For example, I use firefox to search google for: http://bloggingheads.tv/forum/member.php?u=12129

It brings results.

But when I use the module this way:

```
$google_search = Google::Search->Web ( q => "http://bloggingheads.tv/forum/member.php?u=12129" );
@result =  $google_search->all;
```

I get nothing in the array.

Any idea?

Seems like this API doesn't bring the same results like when searching manually, am I missing something?

Comment: Just to clarify things, What I'm trying to achieve is the following: given a URL (like the one mentioned above...), check whether it has a cached version on google, if not , if it even appears on google. thats it.

Comment: You asked this question twice, so now people's advice for your single problem are spread over two separate threads. The other one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744025/googlesearch-perl-module

Comment: I didnt, where? its a different question, and the URL you provided directs to here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem with cyrillic queries. Both `Google::Search` and `REST::Google` from CPAN didn't work for me - they were giving back fewer or no results compared to manual test.

Eventually I wrote a scraping module using `WWW::Mechanize` and `HTML::TreeBuilder`.

Here's a sample to get result stats:

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_content($content);

if (my $div = $tree->look_down(_tag => 'div', id => 'resultStats')) {
    my $stats = $div->as_text();
}
else { warn "no stats" }
```

Comment: You mean to use Mech to submit & receive requests to google, then parse the content I get with HTML::TreeBuilder?

Comment: @soulSurfer2010: yep. this way you'll get results identical to those in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the POD for [Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/~rokr/Google-Search/lib/Google/Search.pm), it looks like it expects you to pass search terms to `Web`, instead of a URL.  I downloaded a [test script](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/ROKR/Google-Search-0.027/script/test) from CPAN, ran it, and it seems to produce expected results:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Google::Search;

my $search = Google::Search->Web(q => "rock");
my $result = $search->first;
while ($result) {
    print $result->number, " ", $result->uri, "\n";
    $result = $result->next;
}
print $search->error->reason, "\n" if $search->error;

__END__

0 http://www.rock.com/
1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_music
2 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_(geology)
3 http://rockyourphone.com/
4 http://rockhall.com/
5 http://www.co.rock.mn.us/
6 http://www.co.rock.wi.us/
7 http://www.rockride.org/
etc...
```

I realize this does not specifically answer your question, but perhaps it steers you in the right direction.

Comment: Well, I even tried to pass: my $search = Google::Search->Web(q => "site: http://bloggingheads.tv/forum/member.php?u=12129" );             still I'm not getting the same results like when searching manually... it always fewer