# How do I check if a page is Google cached in Perl?

Tags: perl, google-api

I tried lots of modules, seems like nothing works well.
Do you have any idea how to check if a page I supply, for example:
http://bloggingheads.tv/forum/member.php?u=12129

Is available on google cache?
I'm using Perl.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google::Search Perl module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744025/googlesearch-perl-module)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try connecting to

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=incache:[url]
```

(Note that the URL should be URL-encoded)

For example:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=incache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fbloggingheads.tv%2Fforum%2Fmember.php%3Fu%3D12129
```

If your page is stored in the Google cache, you will have a search result. If the page isn't, you will have a text saying "Your search did not match any document".

You can try to parse this page to know if your page is in the Google cache.

Comment: Seems like a resonalble solution, I will try it when I get home later. Thanks,